# AJAX to a PHP class that extends, the included classes are not passed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am calling a function via AJAX from a PHP class that extends another class but is not included in that file instead it was included in a different file.
To elaborate here's my code:

Client:

```
$('.username').change(function(){
        var indexOfNumber = $(this).attr('class').indexOf('d');
        var number = $(this).attr('class').substring(Number(indexOfNumber)+1);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'class1.php',
            complete: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });

        $('.userrole.d'+number).html(number);
    });
```

Class1:

```
class class1 extends class2
{
    function class1()
    {
        $this->class2(); << I am getting an error here
    }
```

The error that I am getting is:

Class 'class2' not found in (location of class1).

class2 is included in the config.php file of the project and thus it's not included again in the files, when I call that file from AJAX it doesn't seem to see the previously included PHP files.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way around it is to require the necessary files in class1.php. Or you could include a file that loads a custom autoloader which can dynamically load files when requesting classes.

Comment: I can't do the first option because that will result in an error for declaring the same class twice. Can you explain more about the second part of your answer please: "include a file that loads a custom autoloader"

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error if you only require the file once. If you use `require_once` rather than `require` or `include` it should be fine. It's also better to use `__construct` instead of named constructors: `function class1()`. That is deprecated.

Comment: That worked. Thanks.
Can you still though elaborate about having a custom autoloader?

Comment: Basically, you create a function that receives the name of the class that needs to be loaded. You then write the logic that determines how to find the location of the file with the class based off that name. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php